# Using a MYSQL database to create div tags

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table, populate

Recently started a project which in theory would create new div tags or table rows for each row of information in my MySQL database.

I'm unsure of what language I will tackle this with. I am semi-familiar with writing in PHP.

Here is my theoretical code:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div id="CourseWrap">
<?php 

$sql="SELECT * FROM details";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Employer</th>
<th>LearningProvider</th>
<th>ContractedProvider</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Employer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LearningProvider'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ContractedProvider'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
```

In header.php I connect to the db like so:

```
<?php
//Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "Jobboard","*****", "jobboard");

// Check connection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
    echo "Connected";
  }
?>
```

Note: I'm pretty sure I'm getting something wrong with the Mysqli Side of things.

Question:

How would I go about tackling this? What would be the best option and why?

Comment: I would print $row to check whether my database is returning any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` requires 2 parameters. Example:

```
$con=mysqli_connect('','','','');
$results=mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM table');
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo'<tr><td>'.$row['Employer'].'</td></tr>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

mysqli_query('connection here','your query here');

Comment: Thanks Beneto, Glad some people have manners to explain things :)

Comment: No problem. I just read the code and found the error lol

Answer (score 0):

1. Make PHP report errors

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```
2. Upon reading the error, consult the manual page of the function mentioned in the error message

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm asking for help with. I wrote that it was theoretical code above.